# UserForm to Automatically Populate Fields Based on User Defined Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a User Form that will populate a sheet based off of user defined inputs. The fields include "Measure" and "Offset". These field needs to have row values that increment at a user defined interval. For example, the  "Measure" field needs to have rows that start with 0, ending with a User defined 'Max_Length' and increment by User defined 'Interval'. And for the "Offset" field, it needs to start with 0 and ends with User defined 'Max_Offset' Value and increment by a User defined 'Offset' value.

In other words, Lets just say these are the User Form value inputs for each variable i previously described: Max_Length = 14800, Interval = 10, Max_Offset = 30, Offset = 5

That means there should be 1480 records (14800/10) for Measure field. However each Measure interval should have 6 offset value associated with it (ex. Measure 0 will be in the first 6 rows, and beside each one is the offset value going for 0 - 30 in increments of 5). This means there should be a total of 8880 records (6 * 1480).

The User Form will use Text Boxes to be used as the variable place holders. I have limited experience with VBA and I am not sure how to get past the basic design of the User Form. I'm sorry if this doesn't make a ton of sense or if it is too vague, but any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Added picture to help aid in the explanation.
[Example of Output / Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpKoa.png)

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me exactly what you want to do. What's the *specific* problem you're facing as you try to implement this?  Pick something concrete that you don't know how to do, and explain exactly what problem you're having with it.  "I'm not familiar with VBA" is not something we can really help with here - there are a ton of good tutorials out there if you need to get up to speed with learning about VBA/Excel.

Comment: Might help if you show a screenshot of the expected outcome.

Comment: Sorry about that Tim, in all honesty im just a bit rusty with VBA, as I havent used VB language since my school days years ago. I have updated the original post to include a picture of the output that would be generated from the example values presented in the post. I have a way to do the "Measure" field but the "Offset" field is where im stuck. Im thinking that im going to have to use a nested While loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you just need a couple of nested loops:

```
rw = 1

for measure = 0 to max_len step interval
    for offset = max_offset to 0 step - offset_step

        cells(rw, 1).resize(1,2).value = array(measure, offset) 
        rw = rw +1

    next offset
next measure
```

Comment: Thanks Tim i appreciate this response. It has given me the ground work to finish.